# Select statement using spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
@Repository
public class ApplyLeaveEntityDaoImpl implements ApplyLeaveEntityDao {



    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(ApplyLeaveEntityDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate misJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;




    private static final class EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePathMapper implements
    RowMapper<EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath> {

@Override
public EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
        throws SQLException {
    EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath = new EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath();
    emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath.setFileName(rs.getString("filename"));
    emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath.setFilePath(rs.getString("filepath"));
    return emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath;
}
}

@Override
public EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath getFilePath(final int leaveID){
System.out.println("leaveID"+leaveID);
String sql = "select filename,filepath from "
        + "lms_mas_sickleavefilepath where leaveid = ?";
System.out.println("sql"+sql);
EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath;
try {
    emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath = misJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sql.toString(), new EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePathMapper(),
            leaveID);
    System.out.println("file name"+emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath.getFileName());
}
catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    System.out.println("e"+e);
    e.printStackTrace();

    emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath = null;
}

return emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath;

}

    }
```

i have this above method to fetch one record from the database which contains which i am selecting but i am getting this 
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0 ,even though the record is present in the table.

[image: My table structure]

Comment: What is the content of your `lms_mas_sickleavefilepath` table?

Comment: Seems like there is a mismatch between the ID field name - in the query it is `leaveid` and in the mapper it is `id`. Try to select and print all rows

Comment: @RolandWeisleder check updated question for table structure

Comment: @shachar   check updated question for table structure

Comment: How are you calling this method and with what parameter. If the record cannot be found it isn't there and you are basically querying based on wrong parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum calling like this  EmailBasedApprovalSickFilePath emailBasedApprovalSickFilePath =applyLeaveEntityDao.getFilePath(82414);

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comments, add it to your question. Also is the data really available or only visible to your current transaction in your db browser/tool?

Comment: (shooting in the dark) Is it possible that the `JdbcTemplate` instance you are using is configured to work with a different DB instance? - Can you try to create a record just before you pull it?

Comment: @M.Deinum i found that leavid value is missing from the table